# Circular, brushed metal effect in InkScape?

Tags: vector-graphics, svg, inkscape

[image]

Does anyone know how to make a circular, brushed metal surface with InkScape?

I don't need the "cloud" shape, just the metal background.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to replicate it in photoshop, as I have no Inkscape. I hope it helps you.

First I made a gradient, where I repeat a dark and a light grey every 12.5% of the gradient. Then I place it horizontally on a square canvas. The last step is to apply the 'polar coordinates' filter.

Comment: or a radial blur on "zoom" will make the lighter to darker effect and you don't have to smooth out the sudden stops that "polar coordinates" often has.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw a conic gradient, yet unsupported by the svg specs.

You can hack with gradient meshes on some development builds -another unsupported feature-, use filtering -rely on the renderer-, use "benefits" of anti-aliasing on a halftone pattern, or, stich together many objects with different fills. 
Preferably with the same linear gradient. 
Made this [conic gradient](https://openclipart.org/detail/229848/gradient-corrected) public domain as the latter, give it a try.

Comment: Yet another one, colours adjusted for a closer match: https://openclipart.org/detail/233686/metallic-shine